# How to reach out to a mod on Android.SE?

Tags: discussion, moderators

There are rare cases where one has to (or "strongly wants to") reach out to a mod directly/personally. I understand (and want to emphasize!) these should be exceptions, and a mod should not be *forced* into it – but still, such cases exist (in my 3.5+ years here on Android.SE I felt in that situation 2 times – and you know I'm quite active here; this should show the exception of the need). So how can that be achieved?

- on many/most other sites, there's at least one mod available in the site's chat room (or was shortly, so (s)he can be @ pinged). Not so on Android.SE: I cannot remember when I last saw one of our mods in our room. Must be at least 2 years ago.
- being a mod myself, I of course know about TL. Unfortunately, same situation there; and in some cases one doesn't want to @@ there (or address all mods), to keep the ball low (e.g. now dirty laundry in public ;). There's the possibility to create a "private chat room" and invite – but I'm not sure if that's reserved for mods.
- in some cases, a @ ping doesn't even require a direct response (example: having flagged a question for mod attention, and wanting to add some (important) details forgotten: a second flag isn't permitted by the system, so a simple @ in chat might do)
- we've got no such thing as PM on SE

So let me put my question into separate bullet points:

- Wouldn't it be a good idea if at least one of the mods can be found in our chat room? What speaks against it? If it's your (the mods) workload, you know you can ask for reinforcement. I then might even volunteer and nominate myself to fulfill my own request :)
- Do you rather "keep out of reach" for a reason – or, put into other words, is it generally "unwanted" on SE to reach out to a mod this way?

This is nagging me for the better of a year now. Thus, unable to reach you otherwise, I've decided to bring it up here on Meta (which should be the right place, especially as I'm certainly not the only one with this question in mind).

Please don't get me wrong: this is not a rant, nor am I wanting to blame/accuse someone (some of us have a real-life outside SE as well, unbelievable as it might sound, so there's definitely the possibility of a good reason ;) But having background and advice on this topic pointed out clearly (whichever direction) will certainly be of help.

Comment: I don't know that any of us are intentionally trying to "stay out of reach". I personally don't sit in chat because I simply don't use it (I guess I'm not very chatty?). However, I wouldn't be opposed to perhaps having a separate room that one (or more) of us could just idle in, specifically so that people can ping us for mod-related questions. A few other sites to this. SU, for example, has [Ask a Super User Moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator).

Comment: Thanks, @eldarerathis – and yes, such a room would be a good compromise indeed (keeping you from being "flooded", while still enable us to "reach out"). Might even be enough if it's not "widely announced" but known to the "most active users", who could then act as intermediaries. That would be my 2nd choice if none of you want to join the regular room regularly (oops). As I wrote, I can think of reasons why you might want that, and you have my full respect in that regard :)

Comment: Keeping conversations related specifically to site moderation in a separate room kind of makes sense anyway, IMHO. It'll keep the noise down and then people won't have to talk over other conversations when trying to get help from one of the mods. The only real downside is that it's not private, but you could at least ping a mod there and request a private chat if the situation warranted it.

Comment: Full ack, @eldarerathis (though noise level is rarely high in our regular chat room), sounds good to me – and whoever agrees please upvote that comment ;) If we go that way (don't foget to make each of you room owner there then, so the room doesn't suddenly "drop out"), it might be a good idea to announce it (with link) in an answer here. Title of the question is clear for that, and there are not so many questions tagged `moderators` that it would be too hard to find (but it's still "covered enough" to keep most unwanted noise out). Thanks again – and in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several of the mods hang out frequently in [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts).  You can feel free to talk to us there for any sort of "extended discussion" regarding the site or moderation.  Specific questions should be posted here on Meta.

If your issue relates to something you'd like to discuss privately, you're welcome to ping us to try to arrange a private chat rather than directly discussing it in the public room.

Comment: Good start. I want to know something however. If a user posts something in that chat room without using @ to notify a particular mod and the chat room is not opened in a browser's tab of any of the moderator, would you moderators be notified that a comment has been posted in that chat room *or* would you have to develop a habit of checking that room regularly to see if something has been posted?

Comment: If you don't @ping someone then no notification will be generated. If you do then we'll get a notification in our network-wide inbox. Also, it may be worth noting for anyone who does not frequent chat: you can `@`ping multiple people in a single message (unlike comments).

Comment: Another thing worth noting: pings in chat work only for users who have been in the room __recently__. (Off the top of my head, I think "recently" means the past two weeks, but don't hold me to that.) If they haven't been in the room in over two weeks, you can still type out their names in ping format, but they will __not__ get notifications.

Comment: The mod-questions-chatroom has been fairly inactive and ultimately got frozen automatically, so I don't think there's enough action to keep it going.  Since Dan and Izzy were elected and they're constantly in the regular room (and I've been in there more too recently), I think it's best if users ping us there instead.  Users in that room have been pretty good about not talking over more "on-topic" discussions.  I edited the answer accordingly.